# Two spinners in android app

Tags: android, database, sqlite, spinner

I have problem with my spinners,

in my app are two spinners which gets data from database,

when i choose one option from first spinner, i want to remove this option from second spinner,
and add option which i removed from second spinner to first spinner and vice versa.

How can i do that ?

This is my present code:

```
public void showScoresCalculator() {
    setContentView(R.layout.scores_calculator);

    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/HelveticaProCn.ttf");

    TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
    txt.setTypeface(font);

    TextView team = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.choose_team);
    team.setTypeface(font);     

    TextView group = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.choose_group);
    group.setTypeface(font);    

    TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    title.setTypeface(font);        

    TextView title2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    title2.setTypeface(font);   

    final Spinner sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
    final Spinner sp1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner4);

    final DataBaseHelper.MyData[] items = this.dh.getTeamsNameAndIDs("38");
    final DataBaseHelper.MyData d = items[(int) sp.getSelectedItemId()];

    final DataBaseHelper.MyData[] items2 = this.dh
            .getTeamsNameAndIDs("47");
    final DataBaseHelper.MyData d1 = items2[(int) sp1.getSelectedItemId()];

    final ArrayAdapter<DataBaseHelper.MyData> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<DataBaseHelper.MyData>(
            this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
            this.dh.getTeamsNameAndIDs("38"));

    final ArrayAdapter<DataBaseHelper.MyData> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<DataBaseHelper.MyData>(
            this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
            this.dh.getTeamsNameAndIDs("47"));

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    sp.setAdapter(adapter);
    sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            DataBaseHelper.MyData d = items2[(int) sp1.getSelectedItemId()];
            DataBaseHelper.MyData d1 = items[position];
            home = d.getValue();
            away = d1.getValue();
            if(Integer.valueOf(home.toString()) ==  Integer.valueOf(away.toString())) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nie możesz wybrać dwóch tych samych drużyn.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else {
                showChart(d1.getValue(), d.getValue(), d1.getSpinnerText(), d.getSpinnerText(), "REMIS");
            }
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });

    adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    sp1.setAdapter(adapter1);
    sp1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            DataBaseHelper.MyData d = items[(int) sp.getSelectedItemId()];
            DataBaseHelper.MyData d1 = items2[position];

            home = d.getValue();
            away = d1.getValue();

            if(Integer.valueOf(home.toString()) ==  Integer.valueOf(away.toString())) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nie możesz wybrać dwóch tych samych drużyn.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else {
                showChart(d.getValue(), d1.getValue(), d.getSpinnerText(), d1.getSpinnerText(), "REMIS");
            }

        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });

    final Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
    final Button prev = (Button) findViewById(R.id.prev);

    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            showNewsPage();
        }
    });

    prev.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            showGroupCalculator();
        }
    });
    Page = true;
}
```

Please, help me ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the adapter by removing the selected data from the list. Use **Handler** concept to update adapter.

Set a new adapter on the Spinner via setAdapter(). Or, if it is an ArrayAdapter, use add(), insert(), and remove() to modify the data. Or, if it is a CursorAdapter, requery() it to get fresh data.